# React - how to get real DOM element after component is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jwplayer, lifecycle

I'm trying to run a function after react component render.

```
render: function(){
   return(
      <div id="myId"></div>
   )
}
```

In this function I need to get a real DOM element with  `document.getElementById("myId")`

So I tried to run my function in `componentDidUpdate` but apparently i'ts running before the browser "painted" my div so I'm getting `null`.

Is there an elegant solution for this problem?

Comment: I think you should address it via a reference and not an id. For an example look [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

Comment: but I really need to use the id. I was simplifying the question, I'm using jwplayer.setup ( https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/api/javascript_api_reference/#setup ) and it uses document.getElementById

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right with the assumption that the DOM elements are not necessarily drawn when the `componentDidUpdate` method is called.

You can bypass this with `window.requestAnimationFrame`.

```
onNextFrame() {
  var _this = this;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    var domnode = _this.getDOMNode();
    if (domnode !== undefined) {
      // set your attributes here
      jwplayer(domnode).setup({
        "file": "http://example.com/myVideo.mp4",
        "image": "http://example.com/myImage.png",
        "height": 360,
        "width": 640
      });
    }
  });
},
componentDidMount() {
  this.onNextFrame();
},
componentDidUpdate() {
  this.onNextFrame();
}
```